# Mapkit lat- and longitude of current location

Tags: iphone, mapkit, mkmapview

I imagine its pretty simple, but I wont find it.

I want to show the longitude und latitude of the current user position in two textfields. One for each value.

But it defenatly wont work.

I thought it will be easy with one of the following values... But there are so many possibilitys of lon and lat...

```
mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude
mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude

mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.latitude
mapView.userLocation.location.coordinate.longitude
```

Does anyone know which combination I need to take to simply get the long and lat value?

Thank you in advance from germany

Comment: Either should work.  Where did you put that code and show how you are setting the text field values.

Comment: i put it in viewdidload for testing...

Answer (score 1):

The userLocation may not yet be available in viewDidLoad if that is also where the map view itself is being initialized.

A better place is in the `didUpdateUserLocation` delegate method:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView 
            didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation
{
    NSLog(@"userLocation = %f,%f", mapView.userLocation.coordinate.latitude, 
                                  mapView.userLocation.coordinate.longitude);
}
```

Also make sure that:

- map view's showsUserLocation is checked or set to YES
- map view's delegate is set